# Get value from list and show to a label

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, list

I'm creating a search engine based on SQL database.

Is it possible to get sql data on a List and then show data on labels?

This is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHKELQIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Dictionary;Integrated Security=True");
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Word FROM Dictionary WHERE Word like'%" + lblsearch.Text + "%'", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Dictionary");

            List<string> word = new List<string>();

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Dictionary"].Rows)
            {
                word.Add(row["Word"].ToString());
            }
            Label1.Text = word[0].ToString();
       }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException at line - `Label1.Text = word[0].ToString();`
I don't know why, because that column contains data.

Also how can I position labels where I want, if I need to create new labels for every word?

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is a textbook example of sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: this is a simple project, but i'd gladly avoid vulnerabilities, give me something to learn about it @SeanLange